# pywinauto double click on TreeItem (or open and double click inside)

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I have and application with a list of TreeViews and TreeItems and I need to "double click" in one TreeItem, but I can't find the way to do it.

This is my python code:

```
#Open Application
app = Application(backend="uia").start(ApplicationName, wait_for_idle=True)
time.sleep(2)
dlg = app.top_window()


#Pass and login
app.dlg.child_window(title="", auto_id="LoginAuthPasswordBox", control_type="Edit").set_text('******')
app.dlg.child_window(auto_id="Inici_o de sesión", control_type="Button").click()

time.sleep(60)

#Connect to main window
appfull = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re="IC Business Manager - Interaction Reporter")
dlgfull = appfull.top_window()
```

This code is working OK and, inside dlgfull.print_control_identifiers() I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtJM8.png

And this is mi app:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QWyB.png

I would like to "double click" the first item "Informe estados de agente", OR open it and double clic the first item inside:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHYQy.png

**Could you please help me on this?**

Some lines that i've testing and doesn't work:

```
appfull.dlgfull.child_window(title="Informe de estados de agentes", control_type="TreeItem")..click()

dlgfull.child_window(title="Informe de estados de agentes", control_type="TreeItem").click()

appfull.dlgfull.child_window(title="Informe de estados de agentes", control_type="TreeItem").double_click()

appfull.dlgfull.child_window(title="Informe de estados de agentes", control_type="TreeItem").get_child(child_spec="agentes").click()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GetItem() along with select() or click() method,
you can also use expand() method to expand and view elements that are not visible.

```
treeView = topWin.TreeView    # We get the treeview object here.
# You can get item like this 
node1 = treeView.GetItem([u'TopNodeName', 'node1Name'])
node1.select()

# OR something like this
treeView.GetItem([u'TopNodeName', 'node1Name']).click()

# OR access using index of that element in treeview like:
treeView.GetItem([1, 0]).click()
```